# Error when installing ruby with rvm

Tags: c++, c, ruby, macos, rvm

I am trying to install ruby in MacOS

> In file included from :0:0:
>
> .ext/include/x86_64-darwin14.0.0/ruby/config.h:77:16: error: duplicate
>
> 'unsigned'  #define size_t unsigned int
>
> ```
>             ^ .ext/include/x86_64-darwin14.0.0/ruby/config.h:77:25: error: two or
> ```
>
> more data types in declaration specifiers  #define size_t unsigned int
>
> ```
>                      ^ In file included from <command-line>:0:0: ./include/ruby/missing.h:169:19: warning: conflicting types for
> ```
>
> built-in function 'memmove' [enabled by default]  RUBY_EXTERN void
>
> *memmove(void *, const void *, size_t);
>
> ```
>                ^ In file included from ./include/ruby.h:32:0,
>
>              from main.c:13: ./include/ruby/ruby.h:50:22: fatal error: strings.h: No such file or directory  # include <strings.h>
>
>                   ^ compilation terminated.
> ```

I set env CPP=/usr/bin/cpp

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by following this link: https://gist.github.com/zenkay/3237860

> Mountain Lion supports only XCode 4.4 or greater. Basic 4.4 installer
>   doesn't install Unix's standard command line tools by default. You
>   have to install it using separate package (from Apple Developer's) or
>   directly from XCode 4.4 preference panel (Preferences : Downloads :
>   Components : Install).
>
> When installation is complete, tools are finally available but is not
>   enough. Unfortunately llvm_gcc-4.2 compiler ship with XCode is not
>   suitable to compile Ruby (it works but some features are buggy).
>
> You have to install the stand-alone gcc package.

Basically, i have to install another version of gcc instead of using the one with Xcode.